# Android ViewPager page 2 not being updated

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm working on a multiple choice test app which has a ViewPager and fragments with one question (which may contain images) and possible answers on each page and as some of the images with text might be difficult to read I've added a "home made" zoom functionality with javascript that modifies css on the fly after the question webview is drawn and on a button click (I have given up with pinch-to-zoom as it has many incompatibilities between different Android versions) and it's working great, I have two magnifier icons at the top with + and - and after a click they fire javascript on webview and zoom effect is achieved and zoom factor it's stored in shared settings after that so to have a "default zoom" which is aplied on every page selection.

My goal is that once zoom factor is changed and you move to the next page it keeps and aplies that zoom factor and it's working but not on page 2, where page gets displayed with default zoom.

I guess the problem is related to ViewPager offscreen cache (the weird thing is I've tried with a three questions tests and you change zoom in first page, move to the second and the zoom is not changed and move to the third and the zoom is applied as I intend, very weird though!) so I tried to disable that cache with viewPager.setOffScreenPAgeLimit(0) but it doesn't work. I've also tried the next two blocks of code (separately) with no avail so I'm stuck and any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

PS. The most weird thing is if I set a breakpoint and debug the line with the Javascript gets fired but the webview is not updated, and I'll paste the line in question below as a reference:

```
webViewQuestion.loadUrl("javascript:$('img').css('width', '" + newScaleFactor + "%');" +
    "newFontSize=1*" + newScaleFactor + "/100;" +
    "strNewFontSize=newFontSize.toString()+'em';" +
    "$('#content').css('font-size',strNewFontSize);");

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    mViewPager.invalidate();
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    if(position==1){
        mViewPager.invalidate();
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Edit 1:

OK, the problem is not page 2 as I've stated before, it's the page that follows the one where I click on the zoom button, which has sense as it is the one cached.

For the moment I solved with the next code and it works quite well, I know return POSITION_NONE it's a very bad practice as it redraws all fragments and in fact in my case my views are quite complex and I'm noticing that delay of ev'ry screen being redraw, but what I've done is to set a static variable that indicates where redraw is necessary or not (I set it to true after zoom button click and set it to false in onPageSelected as it is shown below). For the moment is working but anyway I hope someone come up with a better solution.

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    if(mustRedraw){
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mViewPager.invalidate();
        mustRedraw=false;
    }
```

Comment: have you tried with `viewpager.setOffScreenPageLimit(1)`

Comment: I did it @Akhil, tried with 0 and 1 but it doesn't work :(